# loadVariables() and LoadVars

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, loadvars

I am currently developing an Flash Movie which sends a simple POST request with a few parameters to a PHP URL. The only problem is that I am not sure which of two (loadVariables & LoadVars) methods I should use. What are the pros and cons?

Comment: You tagged this question `[actionscript-2]` and `[actionscript-1]`, are you using both?

Comment: I added both tags because I thought actionscript 1 didn't have LoadVars. While actionscript 1 and actionscript 2 had loadVariables.

Comment: That is true, since `LoadVars` is a class and classes were introduced in AS2. That being said, it would probably be better to remove the `[actionscript-1]` tag since your question only applies to AS2+.

Comment: I've removed the actionscript 1 tag, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `LoadVars` Class:

> The `LoadVars` class is an alternative to the `loadVariables()` function for transferring variables between a Flash Lite and a web server over HTTP. Use the `LoadVars` class to obtain verification of successful data loading and to monitor download progress.
>
> The `LoadVars` class lets you send all the variables in an object to a specified URL and load all the variables at a specified URL into an object. It also lets you send specific variables, rather than all the variables, which can make your application more efficient. Use the `LoadVars.onLoad` handler to ensure that your application runs when data is loaded, and not before.
>
> The LoadVars class works much like the XML class; it uses the methods `load()`, `send()`, and `sendAndLoad()` to communicate with a server. The main difference between the `LoadVars` class and the XML class is that `LoadVars` transfers ActionScript name and value pairs, rather than an XML DOM tree stored in the XML object. The `LoadVars` class follows the same security restrictions as the XML class.
>
> **- Copied verbatim from [Adobe Flash Platform - LoadVars](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-78c7.html)**

## `loadVariables` Function:

> Reads data from an external file, such as a text file or text generated by ColdFusion, a CGI script, Active Server Pages (ASP), PHP, or Perl script, and sets the values for variables in a target movie clip. This action can also be used to update variables in the active SWF file with new values.
>
> The text at the specified URL must be in the standard MIME format `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (a standard format used by CGI scripts). Any number of variables can be specified. For example, the following phrase defines several variables:
>
> ```
> company=Macromedia&address=600+Townsend&city=San+Francisco&zip=94103
> ```
>
> **- Copied verbatim from [Adobe Flash Platform - loadVariables Function](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7fec.html)**